# Reverse search for results found using wildcard search - which query did the result come from?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a set of messages that have been found from a database by searching using e.g. `WHERE message LIKE 'Event % succeeded%'`

There are various types of msg that link to events, and I want to be able to link the found messages back to the event that they correspond to. I don't have access to the original database that was searched.

The events are like this:

| event | sql_query | service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| event1 | Event % failed% | service1 |
| event2 | Event % succeeded% | service1 |
| event3 | Event % has added % | service2 |

In my `df_temp` below I want to be able to return the row of the above table (`df`) that the `message` in the `list_of_events` corresponds to.

I'm struggling to relate the LIKE wildcard search in SQL back to the actual messages.

```py
import pandas as pd

query_ref_dict = {
    "event1": {
        "sql_query": "Event % failed%",
        "service": "service1",
    },
    "event2": {"sql_query": "Event % succeeded%", "service": "service1"},
    "event3": {
        "sql_query": "Event % has added %",
        "service": "service2",
    },
}

list_of_events = [{'id': 1, 'message': 'Event XYY123 succeeded in 20s' , 'service': 'service1'},
        {'id': 2, 'message': 'Event XYY123 has added X records in 20s' , 'service': 'service2'},
                  {'id': 3, 'message': 'Event has failed' , 'service': 'service2'}]


df = pd.DataFrame(query_ref_dict).T

for event in list_of_events:
    serv = event['service']
    msg = event['message']
    df_temp = df.loc[ (df['service'] == serv) & (df['sql_query'].str.contains(msg)) ]
    print(df_temp.index.tolist())
```

Desired output

```
['event2']
['event3']
['event1']
```

EDIT - initial solution

Building on the suggestion below, I want to this to be able to work with a provided table of services and messages to match against.

This works, but is probably not very efficient.

Open to any ideas for improving on this.

```py
import re

df['regex'] = df['sql_query'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("%", "(.*)"))


for event in list_of_events:
    serv = event['service']
    msg = event['message']
    df['check'] = df['regex'].apply(lambda x: bool(re.search(x, msg)))
    df_temp = df.loc[ (df['service'] == serv) & (df['check'] == True) ]
    print(f"{msg}, returns: {df_temp.index.tolist()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this,

```
import pandas as pd
import re 

query_ref_dict = {
    "event1": {
        "sql_query": "Event % failed%",
        "service": "service1",
    },
    "event2": {"sql_query": "Event % succeeded%", "service": "service1"},
    "event3": {
        "sql_query": "Event % has added %",
        "service": "service2",
    },
}

list_of_events = [{'id': 1, 'message': 'Event XYY123 succeeded in 20s' , 'service': 'service1'},
        {'id': 2, 'message': 'Event XYY123 has added X records in 20s' , 'service': 'service2'},
                  {'id': 3, 'message': 'Event has failed' , 'service': 'service2'}]


df = pd.DataFrame(query_ref_dict).T

for event in list_of_events:
    serv = event['service']
    msg = event['message']
    if re.match("Event(.*)succeeded(.*)", msg):
        msg = "Event % succeeded%"
    elif re.match("Event(.*)failed", msg):
        msg = "Event % failed%"
    else:
        msg = "Event % has added %"
    print(msg)
    df_temp = df.loc[ (df['service'] == serv) & (df['sql_query'].str.contains(msg)) ]
    print(df_temp.index.tolist())
```